# ansible: ec2_asg module creates extra instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ansible, autoscaling

I am using the following task to create an `aws` auto scaling group.

```
- name: Create auto scaling group
  ec2_asg:
    name: "{{ els_aws_asg_name }}"
    launch_config_name: "{{ rv_ec2_lc.result.launch_configuration_name }}"
    region: "{{ VPC_REGION }}"
    min_size: 1
    max_size: 5
    desired_capacity: 1
    vpc_zone_identifier: "{{ els_aws_private_vpc_subnets[0] }}"
    load_balancers: "{{ rv_ec2_elb.elb.name }}"
    notification_topic: "{{ els_aws_sns_admin }}"
    replace_all_instances: yes 
    tags:
      - Name: "{{ els_aws_asg_name }}"
```

However, although the `desired_capacity` is set to **1**, after completion I see **2** running `ec2` instances.

Before running the task, there was also **1** instance (so the specific task actually **adds** one more).

Why that might be happening?

**update**:

from further investigation it turns out that when checking in the `aws` console, one instance seems to be attached in the specific auto scaling group. So the above behavior kind of makes sense.

When I terminate the instance that seems to be attached to the asg, the asg brings up a new one.

When I terminate the **other** instance, the asg takes no action.

Now the question becomes how to attach an **existing** instance in the asg, given that the [ec2_asg](http://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/ec2_asg_module.html) does not seem to provide such functionality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no way in Ansible to attach an existing instance to an ASG. The only way is to use AWS console or CLI which is not bad since you will be doing this only once.

See: [Attach EC2 Instances to Your Auto Scaling Group](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/autoscaling/latest/userguide/attach-instance-asg.html)